# webpack won't set to production. Defaults to development

Tags: node.js, webpack, production, webpack-4

I'm lost. I've been following a Udemy Webpack 4 tutorial on webpack and I am stuck on having different configs for different modes.

I can build from my production config just fine, but when it comes to running the node server, it's not set to production.

I have my main.js write this:

```
console.log(`Environment is: ${process.env.NODE_ENV`}
```

and I have only seen it in show as Development.

Here's my package.json's script to run production: I run **npm run build** and then **npm run prod**

```
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack --config=config/webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config=config/webpack.prod.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --inspect --watch config --watch src/server 
     src/server/main.js",
    "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node src/server/main.js"
  },
```

It was mentioned that I needed to define NODE_ENV in the webpack prod config in the plugin section. Here is how I have it:

```
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV:'"production"'
        }
    }),
```

I've tried it in different ways:  'process.env': {'NODE_ENV': JSON.Stringify("production")} and a couple of other ways and I have had no luck.

Here is my repository to see my complete config:  https://github.com/PepperAddict/webpack-express

I would appreciate any help even recommendation on a better way to set this up. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Below is mine config using webpack 4

```
"prod": "webpack -p --mode=production --config webpack.prod.js",
"start": "webpack --mode=development --config webpack.dev.js",
```

And if you want to set NODE_ENV you can do like this

```
"prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production& webpack -p --mode=production",
```

Hope that help